# What is wrong with this Jquery expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since I upgraded my project from JQuery 1.7.1 to 1.11.0, I am getting this error in one of my js which used to work fine before

The error I am getting is

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .formsetFormField:not(.treeLevel):not([name$=-TOTAL_FORMS]):not([name$=-INITIAL_FORMS]):not([name$=-MAX_NUM_FORMS]), input[type=checkbox][name$=-DELETE], input[type=hidden][name$=-slide], , input[type=file]

My code is something like this

```
if (typeof opts.getAllInputs === "undefined") {
                node._getAllInputs = function(withManagementForm) {
                    withManagementForm = (typeof withManagementForm === "undefined") ? withManagementForm : false;
                    if (withManagementForm) {
                        return $(this).find("> .nestedFormsetsFieldsSection > li > input:not(.treeLevel), > .nestedFormsetsFieldsSection > li > textarea");
                    } else {
                        return $(this).find("> .nestedFormsetsFieldsSection > li > input:not(.treeLevel):not([name$=-TOTAL_FORMS]):not([name$=-INITIAL_FORMS]):not([name$=-MAX_NUM_FORMS]), > .nestedFormsetsFieldsSection > li > textarea");
                    }
                };
            } else {
                node._getAllInputs = opts.getAllInputs;
}
```

I tried many approaches like
1. Fixing this expression
2. Tried using multiple version of Jquery. I made an object of 1.7.1 and used following approach

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_7_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

But I end up getting more errors.

The only solution I see is if someone can help me fixing this expression according to Jquery 1.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys for wasting your time. I did find the problem. The function getAllInputs was called in some other js and I found there were two commas for no reason (which was caught in the exception error).

I don't know why it wasn't caught in older version. And that was the reason and because of that it never came to my mind that problem could be in some other js and not with version upgrade.

Anyways I replaced it with single comma and it worked like a charm :).

Thanks all for all the effort and help.

Comment: @kunalManwar that's what mentioned in the answer, but glad you get it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

As in this code seems to be error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .formsetFormField:not(.treeLevel):not([name$=-TOTAL_FORMS]):not([name$=-INITIAL_FORMS]):not([name$=-MAX_NUM_FORMS]), input[type=checkbox][name$=-DELETE], input[type=hidden][name$=-slide], , input[type=file]

so you can try this:

```
$(this).find('.formsetFormField:not(.treeLevel):not([name$="-TOTAL_FORMS"]):not([name$="-INITIAL_FORMS"]):not([name$="-MAX_NUM_FORMS"]), input[type="checkbox"][name$="-DELETE"], input[type="hidden"][name$="-slide"], input[type="file"]');
```

what seems to me is when using attribute selectors, you should use `""` quotes to make it string representation like for example: `[name$="-MAX_NUM_FORMS"]`.

---

Another thing i noticed that you have two commas `, ,` here:

```
[name$=-slide], , input[type=file]
```

at the end of your selector.

Comment: I tried that quote approach too but error still persists :(. I don't understand from where this , , is coming.

Answer (score 0):

i tested the code in my system...seems there is not any error..try the code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var opts="a";  //just delete that
var node="a";    //just delete that
if (typeof opts.getAllInputs === "undefined") {
                node._getAllInputs = function(withManagementForm) {
                    withManagementForm = (typeof withManagementForm === "undefined") ? withManagementForm : false;
                    if (withManagementForm) {
                        return $(this).find("> .nestedFormsetsFieldsSection > li > input:not(.treeLevel), > .nestedFormsetsFieldsSection > li > textarea");
                    } else {
                        return $(this).find("> .nestedFormsetsFieldsSection > li > input:not(.treeLevel):not([name$=-TOTAL_FORMS]):not([name$=-INITIAL_FORMS]):not([name$=-MAX_NUM_FORMS]), > .nestedFormsetsFieldsSection > li > textarea");
                    }
                };
            } else {
                node._getAllInputs = opts.getAllInputs;
}
</script>
```

Comment: May be this expression gives error when it successfully find that dom element? May be if you look at error you can give me an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hey please use `noconflict` for new version not for old since your code is compatible to `Jquery 1.7.1` then you need to write below code for `noconflict`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jQuery_1_11_1 = $.noConflict(true);
  </script>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Nope! Didn't worked. I end up getting more errors :(

Comment: Is Your code is working with 1.7.1 if you removed new library?